# Can github copilot be configured with visual studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I heard it can be done with Resharper. Any clues on how to do it? Do I have to write a custom extension? That seems like a hell of work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use [GitHub](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/468#issue-1128882453) Copilot. Via the extension you can use GitHub Copilot under Visual Studio without any problems. Please have a look at the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilotvs).

To add extensions under Visual Studio please [go to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2022):
**Tools > Options > Environment > Extensions**